# pubnub asyncio not publishing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, pubnub

I am using `PubNub Asyncio` library to publish the data, below is my code.

```
import asyncio
import os

from pubnub.exceptions import PubNubException
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub_asyncio import PubNubAsyncio

def publish_callback(result, status):
    print(status)

class PubNubIntegrator:
    def __init__(self):
        print("In initialize")
        pn_configuration = PNConfiguration()
        pn_configuration.publish_key = os.environ['PUB_KEY']
        pn_configuration.subscribe_key = os.environ['SUB_KEY']
        pn_configuration.ssl = True
        self.pubnub = PubNubAsyncio(pn_configuration)


    async def publish_data(self, message, channel_name):
        print('message on channel {0}'.format(channel_name))
        try:
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.pubnub.publish().channel(channel_name).message(message).future()).add_done_callback(publish_callback)
        except PubNubException as e:
            print("Error while publishing data", message)
```

And I am calling it from another function,

```
async def stream(self):
        result = { "mesage": "data"} 
        pn_integrator = PubNubIntegrator()
        await pn_integrator.publish_data(result, 'demo_channel')
```

But it doesn't work and not publishing the data to channel.

Comment: Which version of Python? Which version of PubNub Python Async.io SDK? Can you [enable PubNub Python SDK logs and reproduce](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-aiohttp/pubnub-python-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and provide - which you many want to report direct to [PubNub Support due to the data included in the logs](https://support.pubnub.com) - pub/sub keys and such]? But do make sure you are on the latest version of PubNub SDK and preferably on v3.7 of Python itself. the most recent update may be the solution: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-aiohttp/changelog

Comment: have you made any progress based on my suggestions? If necessary, please submit your inquiry to [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/status) and include this SO link so we can post back with an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have submitted a ticket to `PubNub`

Comment: Did support give you any insights?